# ​Is there a way to do broadcast join in Spark 2.1 in java

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I know that there exists a way in scala as mentioned below.

```
val joined_df = df1.join(broadcast(df2), "key")
```

How can I do the Broadcast join in Java.
Do I have to do sc.broadcast (df2) and use that in the join? Will it be called as broadcast join then?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I do the Broadcast join in Java.

Exactly the same way.

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast;

Datset<Row> joined = df1.join(broadcast(df2), "key");
```